# In Logstash how to extract substring in a bigger string?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-grok, grok, oniguruma

Feeling difficulty in writing grok patterns.Please help

I have `GetIndicatorsByAnalysisProcessIDServlet service method is called` and in this how to extract only `GetIndicatorsByAnalysisProcess` and text GetIndicatorsByAnalysisProcess will not be same

Here challenging i felt is truncating string from backward direction

i followed up

```
grok {
  match => ["destinationid", "(?<fieldname>discard.{7})"]
}
```

it high-lets considering number of characters from start

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to have the first word in a variable.
This is achievable via

```
(?<fieldname>[^\s]*)\s*
```

with sample output from it

```
{
  "fieldname": [
    [
      "GetIndicatorsByAnalysisProcessIDServlet"
    ]
  ]
}
```

In case you have various beginnings with optional spaces but an exactly same ending of the sentence, the effective regexp will be different.

Comment: i want to extract only GetIndicatorsByAnalysisProcessID from 'GetIndicatorsByAnalysisProcessIDServlet service method is called' and 'GetIndicatorsByAnalysisProcessID ' can vary like GetIndicatorsByPricingDate that need to extract before servlet 'GetIndicatorsByAnalysisProcessIDServlet service method is called'